# R download file redirect

Tags: r

Hi I am following a online class and trying to download the `rda` dataset provided by the prof.

I tried to run exactly the same command as provided in the class:

```
download.file("https://dl.dropbox.com/u/7710864/courseraPublic/samsungData.rda", destfile="./samsungData.rda", method="curl")
load('./samsungData.rda')
```

When I go to the download folder, open the `rda` file in vi, this is what I see:

```
<html>
   <head><title>Found</title></head>
  <body>
    <h1>Found</h1>
    <p>The resource was found at <a href="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/7710864/courseraPublic/samsungData.rda">https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/7710864/courseraPublic/samsungData.rda</a>;
you should be redirected automatically.

<!--  --></p>
    <hr noshade>
    <div align="right">WSGI Server</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Clearly there is a redirect here and the download file command did not follow it smartly. When I open up that URL in the browser, it will be successfully redirected.

I took a look at the help manual of `download.file` there is no such thing as following redirect.

***Can anyone show me how to follow the redirect?***

Comment: Why not download the file in your browser instead?

Comment: Use the `downloader` package, which provides a flexible `download` function that works across different protocols.

Comment: @Aaron For easy reproducibility.

Comment: Make the professor fix his links in the first place.

Comment: I think you should be able to specify `download.file(..., extra='-L')` and have it work.

Comment: @Thomas Thanks so much for the `extra`. Maybe you can post your answer below and I will mark it as accepted. THanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try specifying an `extra` argument, which will pass command-line arguments to curl:

```
download.file("https://dl.dropbox.com/u/7710864/courseraPublic/samsungData.rda", 
              destfile="./samsungData.rda",
              method="curl",
              extra='-L')
```