# Download files in R with URLs that do not end with the file extensions

Tags: r, url, zip, gtfs, gtfstools

Does anyone have a trick up there sleeve for downloading GTFS using R when the URL doesn't end with ".zip"?
For instance, this works:

```
download.file(url = "http://www.transperth.wa.gov.au/TimetablePDFs/GoogleTransit/Production/google_transit.zip", destfile = "temp.zip")
```

But the following create files of the right size that will not open:

```
download.file(url = "http://transitfeeds.com/p/ptv/497/latest/download", destfile = "temp.zip")

download.file(url = "http://transitfeeds.com/p/ptv/497/latest/download", destfile = "temp")
```

I suspect there is something fundamental I need to understand about urls but I don't know where to beging looking so any pointers would be appreciated.

Cheers,

Anthony

Comment: In the transitfeeds example you gave, are you sure there is anything to download? It gives a 404 error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your link is probably a redirect. Try using the `httr` package as described here [R download file redirect error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47603195/r-download-file-redirect-error)

```
library(httr)

url <- "http://transitfeeds.com/p/ptv/497/latest/download"    
GET(
        url = url,
        write_disk("gtfs.zip"),
        verbose()
    ) -> res
```

I was able to download the file and open it. If it works you can remove the verbose() part.

Comment: Thank you @kukuk1de, "redirect" was the term I needed, the http library seems much better suited for the task, and the verbose object will come in handy from now on! I owe you a beer!

Comment: @Anthony, good to hear your problem is solved. If you think my answer was helpful please accept it as solution. And thanks for the beer :-)

Answer (score 0):

@kukul1de answer does the trick.

I'd also note that transitfeeds links to the official download URL. The link is located on the right, under "About This GTFS Feed" (check the image below):

[image]

Then you can right-click and select "Copy Link Location", which will give you the official URL with a `.zip` extension, which you can use in conjunction with `download.file()`.

HOWEVER, this specific URL links to a file which is actually a `.zip` that contains many folders, each one containing a distinct GTFS file, and not a `.zip` in the GTFS format.

Was it an actual GTFS `.zip` file you would be able to use either `{gtfstools}` or `{tidytransit}` to read it, but unfortunately the file format does not allow it. Check it out:

```r
tmp <- tempfile(pattern = "gtfs", fileext = ".zip")

download.file(
    "http://data.ptv.vic.gov.au/downloads/gtfs.zip", 
    destfile = tmp
)

zip::zip_list(tmp)
#>                 filename compressed_size uncompressed_size           timestamp
#> 1                     1/               0                 0 2021-02-22 19:23:20
#> 2                    10/               0                 0 2021-02-22 19:23:20
#> 3  10/google_transit.zip            3231              4011 2021-02-22 19:09:56
#> 4                    11/               0                 0 2021-02-22 19:23:20
#> 5  11/google_transit.zip           29966             32109 2021-02-22 19:10:12
#> 6   1/google_transit.zip         7262254           7625276 2021-02-22 19:01:56
#> 7                     2/               0                 0 2021-02-22 19:23:20
#> 8   2/google_transit.zip         5667379           6269932 2021-02-22 19:03:34
#> 9                     3/               0                 0 2021-02-22 19:23:20
#> 10  3/google_transit.zip         6714271           7782585 2021-02-22 19:05:04
#> 11                    4/               0                 0 2021-02-22 19:23:20
#> 12  4/google_transit.zip        66336783          67508547 2021-02-22 19:23:16
#> 13                    5/               0                 0 2021-02-22 19:23:20
#> 14  5/google_transit.zip        27834469          27962731 2021-02-22 19:06:16
#> 15                    6/               0                 0 2021-02-22 19:23:20
#> 16  6/google_transit.zip        13730731          14172729 2021-02-22 19:09:10
#> 17                    7/               0                 0 2021-02-22 19:23:20
#> 18  7/google_transit.zip           46932             50417 2021-02-22 19:09:24
#> 19                    8/               0                 0 2021-02-22 19:23:20
#> 20  8/google_transit.zip          574316            580906 2021-02-22 19:09:42
```

Let's say you want to read the GTFS file inside the `1/` folder. Then you can unzip this file with `zip::unzip()`:

```r
tmpd <- file.path(tempdir(), "tmp_gtfs")
dir.create(tmpd)

zip::unzip(tmp, files = "1/google_transit.zip", exdir = tmpd)

list.files(tmpd)
#> [1] "1"
list.files(file.path(tmpd, "1"))
#> [1] "google_transit.zip"
```

And read it with `{gtfstools}` or `{tidytransit}`. It depends on what you wanna do with the file:

```r
gtfs_path <- file.path(tmpd, "1", "google_transit.zip")

gt_gtfs <- gtfstools::read_gtfs(gtfs_path)
names(gt_gtfs)
#> [1] "agency"         "routes"         "trips"          "stops"         
#> [5] "calendar"       "calendar_dates" "shapes"         "stop_times"

tt_gtfs <- tidytransit::read_gtfs(gtfs_path)
names(tt_gtfs)
#> [1] "agency"         "routes"         "trips"          "stops"         
#> [5] "calendar"       "calendar_dates" "shapes"         "stop_times"
```

Comment: Thanks for looking into this. My aim has been to get GTFS for multiple Australian cities but unfortunately the official Melbourne feed is split by provider and/or mode. The "latest version" on transitfeeds.com has already merged the Melbourne GTFS so it simplifies the remaining processing in my script. Yes, the tidytransit library is what I've been using as the documentation has been much more helpful that the other gtfs r libraries